# Why am I getting an undefined when trying to get a Guild in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm pretty new to working on Discord bots, but I'm trying to create a bot for Discord that gets all the members in a guild, so they can be used later on. But everytime I try to get the guild with its ID it gives an undefined back, even though I know I put in the right ID.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const members = client.guilds.cache.get("guildID");

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
    console.log(members);
});

client.login('token');
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you know what version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: That code looks correct to me, are you sure your bot is a member of the guild you are trying to fetch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't being very clear. You stated you want your bot to get all members in a guild, but you proceed to get a guild ID instead.

Assuming you want to get all members in a guild. First thing you need is [Privileged Gateway Intents](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway) enabled in your bot and implemented in your code.

**Step 1: Enable Intents**

1. Go to your [Bot App Dev](https://discord.com/developers/applications)
2. Select your bot
3. Head to the `Bot` section of your bot and scroll down till you see "Privileged Gateway Intents" and select both "PRESENCE INTENT" and "SERVER MEMBERS INTENT
   "

*Example*

[image]

**Step 2: Implementing In Code**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ ws: { intents: new Discord.Intents(Discord.Intents.ALL) }});
                                          ^^^^^^^
                             This is what is making you access all server members within a guild
```

**Code for getting all server members:**

```
// If prefix not set: do this: const prefix = "!"; whatever you want
const prefix = "!";
// Usernames
const members = message.guild.members.cache.map(member => member.user.tag);
// ID's
const members = message.guild.members.cache.map(member => member.user.id);

if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "test")){ // Gets all members usernames within the guild this message was sent on.
console.log(members) // Logs all each members username
}
```

In depth but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's just:

```
client.guilds.get("guildID");
```

and not:

```
client.guilds.cache.get("guildID");
```

Comment: As of v12 you need to add `.cache` for managers

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

```js
client.guilds.fetch("guildID");
```

Also, I recommend you put that line in your ready event or somewhere where you are sure the client has fully logged in when ran to make sure that it is logged in when you run that.

Answer (score 0):

Before client is ready, use `client.guilds.fetch('<guild id>')` which returns a promise. Note that before the ready event is triggered many things on the client are uninitialized such as `client.user`

Answer (score 0):

Put the `const members = client.guilds.cache.get("guildID");` inside the ready event.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```js
const members = client.guilds.cache.get("guildID");

list.members.cache.forEach(member => console.log(member.user.username));
```